# nested id object not getting deleted in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Hello I am trying to delete pushed (data) `_id` from a document array, but I am getting no response while executing.

Also, since it is a relational `_id` which I am trying to delete. How can I delete  from the collection it is actually stored ?

here is my **delete route:-**

```
router.delete('/userDelete/:userId', checkAuth , (req, res, next) =>{
    if(req.userData.role2 === 'admin') {
        Admin.findOneAndDelete({_id: req.params.userId},{ $pull: { 'admins.users': {_id: req.params._id}}},{new: true}) 
        .exec()
        .then(result => {
            res.status(200).send(["Deleted"]);
        })
        .catch(err =>{
        if (err.code == 500)
                    res.status(500).send(["Didn't get deleted"]);
            else
            return next(err);
        });
    }else{
        res.send(["Unauthorized. Not deleted"]);
    }
});
```

**This is the nested object looks like :-**

```
{
    "admins": {
        "users": [
            "5d0364048db4957100f33fea" //<===want to delete this relational id
        ],
        "email": "1cf1eede89@himail.online",
        "password": "$2a$10$vHyGxX9P.t0/ybKcmIzkc.ZCX18oHaVnvTgJIWA2gTNzJ3TCdXS4a",
    "_id": "5d0339d5b4b28b6ddff06802",
    "companyName": "GH",
    "__v": 0
}
```

This is my **controller** :-

```
var admin = new Admin();
    admin.companyName = req.body.companyName;
    admin.admins = {
                    email : req.body.email,
                    password: req.body.password,
                    users : [] 
    };
```

*Is is also possible to delete records from each and every collections where particular `_id` data is located ?*

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the Document and update,

Data

```
{
    "_id" : "5d0339d5b4b28b6ddff06802",
    "admins" : {
        "users" : [
            "5d0364048db4957100f33fea"
        ]
    }
}
```

Query

```
db.users.updateOne(
    { _id: req.params.userId },
    {
        $pull: {
            "admins.users": req.params._id
        }
    }
);
```

Result

```
{
    "_id" : "5d0339d5b4b28b6ddff06802",
    "admins" : {
        "users" : [ ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot hard code it. It should be dynamically done.

Comment: yes just pass your data, its just for referance instead of hardcoded id pass your id

Comment: `$pull` should also be dynamic and as you can see there is not `_id` key in `users": ["5d0364048db4957100f33fea" ]`. Then how will I call ?

Comment: I think it will not find as `"admins.users": req.params._id` got no  `_id`. See my json response

Comment: you have array directy =>  `"users": [
            "5d0364048db4957100f33fea" //<===want to delete this relational id
        ],`

not like  `"users": [
           { _id: "5d0364048db4957100f33fea"} //<===want to delete this relational 
        ]`

Comment: Yes exactly because I am pushing `_id` from child schema in this array. So in mongoDb it looks like `0:ObjectId("5d0364048db4957100f33fea")`. So in this case how i will I delete it ?

Comment: try above query and please error share you are getting

Comment: Tried , nothing happens. It is showing message "Deleted" but id is not getting deleted from database array

Comment: What about my route url ? How will I mention `admins.users` /:objectid in route . I didn't get your ID format thing.